# How to find the consecutive numbers from set in python [9,12,13,11,10] true [17,1,2,3,5] true [19,22,23,27,55] false

Tags: python

Input: a = {737739, 737740, 737741, 737735}

```
listA = {737739, 737740, 737741, 737735}
sorted_list = sorted(listA) 
range_list=list(range(min(listA), max(listA)+1)) 
if sorted_list == range_list: 
    print("listA has consecutive numbers") 
else: 
    print("listA has no consecutive numbers")
```

Expected output: {737739, 737740, 737741}

Any suggestion

Comment: Please make some kind of attempt to solve this on your own.

Comment: I have made my own attempt but if it is continuous numbers it works but any diff numbers in list it doesnt work. For.eg: {1,2,3,4} it works. {1,2,3,8} it is not working.

Comment: Post your attempt here

Comment: This isn't a dict, it's a set: `{737739, 737740, 737741, 737735}` is that really what you have?

Comment: yes am having a set. from this set i need to find 3 or more than 3 consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Shadowcodder sorted_list = sorted(listA)
#sorted(l) ==
range_list=list(range(min(listA), max(listA)+1))
if sorted_list == range_list:
    print("listA has consecutive numbers")
else:
    print("listA has no consecutive numbers")
this is my attempt. In this if the numbers continuous then it says consecutive but i need to find consecutive numbers from like this set {737739, 737740, 737741, 737735}.

Comment: @Aro Jo, I mean edit the question and post it there

Comment: `any(sorted(a)[i+2] - sorted(a)[i] == 2 for i in range(len(a)-2))`